# Google Drive API para buscar apenas imagens

Tags: api, google-drive-api

Recentemente comecei a estudar a API do Google Drive. Estou conseguindo listar todos os arquivos do Drive e tenho acesso a todos seus atributos. Porém, foi solicitado que eu fizesse uma busca apenas pelos arquivos de imagens.

O que fiz ? Joguei o código de busca dentro de um JavaScript:

```
if(file.extension === 'jpg' || file.extension === 'png')
```

Mas aí que tá. Minha busca está analisando todos os arquivos do drive e listando apenas os .jpg e .png, tornado minha busca muito mal otimizada. Gostaria de saber se alguém poderia me ajudar. Quero que minha busca vasculhe o Drive e retorne apenas os arquivos de extensão img.

Segue o link do da API https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js . Desde já, grato.

Comment: Em `gapi.client.drive.files.list` você pode usar a propriedade `q` para busca de arquivos. Ainda nessa propriedade, você pode passar o valor de `mimeType` para buscar determinados tipos de arquivos. Mais exemplos: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters

Comment: Você poderia me dar um exemplo de como usar essa propriedade q ?

Answer (score 1):

Como eu não sei como está seu código, irei deixar um trecho de como você pode fazer.

Como eu disse no meu comentário, basta adicionar a propriedade `q` e utilizar um dos operadores abaixo seguido do valor que queres.

**Operadores:**

- `contains`   O conteúdo de uma string está presente na outra.
- `=`          O conteúdo de uma string ou booleano é igual ao outro.
- `!=`         O conteúdo de uma string ou booleano não é igual ao outro.
- `<`          O valor é menor que outro.
- `<=`         O valor é menor ou igual a outro.
- `>`          O valo ré maior que outro.
- `>=`         O valor é maior ou igual a outro.
- `in`         Um elemento dentro de uma coleção.
- `and`        Retorna itens que correspondem a ambas as cláusulas.
- `or`         Retorna itens que correspondem a qualquer cláusula.
- `not`        Nega uma cláusula de pesquisa.
- `has`        Uma coleção contém um elemento que corresponde aos parâmetros.

**Como fazer:**

```
"q": "<campo>" <operador> "<valor"> ["<campo>" <operador> "<valor"> ],
```

**Exemplo:**

```
function listFiles() {
    gapi.client.drive.files.list({
        'pageSize': 10,
        'q': "mimeType contains 'image/jpeg' or mimeType contains 'image/png'",
        'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log('Files:');
        let files = response.result.files;

        if (files && files.length > 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                let file = files[i];

                console.log(file.name + ' (' + file.id + ')');
            }
        } else {
            console.log('No files found.');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Você não sabe o tanto que esse post me ajudou. Valeu mesmo irmão. Continue semeando conhecimento !!!

Comment: Apenas mais uma dúvida. Agora eu consigo listar o tipo de arquivo que desejo. Como no seguinte código: